# How to index a Deedle Frame with Excel's dates as keys?

Tags: excel, dataframe, f#, deedle

Say I'm given a column "Date" with values that look like:
    03/10/86, 06/10/86, 07/10/86, etc...

It is not as simple as doing `Frame.indexRowsDate("Date")`.
My current solution is to create on the Excel 3 extra columns:

- Year
- Month
- Day

with values:

- =Year(A2)
- =Month(A2)
- =Day(A2)

(for row 2, where A is the column with the dates)

and then use this function:

```
let toDateTime (os:ObjectSeries<_>) =
  let year = (os.Get "Year") :?> int)
  let month = (os.Get "Month" :?> int)
  let day = (os.Get "Day" :?> int)
  DateTime(year,month,day)

Frame.indexRowsUsing toDateTime frame
```

**Solution**
Given the provided answer, the new `toDateTime` looks like this:

```
let toDateTime (os:ObjectSeries<_>) =
  DateTime.Parse((os.Get "Date") :?> string)
```

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: @robkuz I wonder if there is a better way of doing it

Comment: Why does the one column approach does not work?

Comment: @robkuz Either Deedle is trying to construct a DateTime like this: DateTime("03/10/86"), but that is not a valid constructor for DateTime or Deedle is training to construct a DateTime with the Excel integer representation of that day, which doesn't follows the convention of DateTime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant use the constructor function for DateTime and feed it a string.

```
let d = new DateTime("03/10/86")
```

but you can use the `static member TryParse` which will return a tuple to you

```
let (success, date) = DateTime.TryParse("03/10/86")
if success then
   //use date here
else
   //do some error handling
```